# Confusion in Panda mode ()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
x = df["Calories"].mode()[0]
df["Calories"].fillna(x, inplace = True)
print(df.to_string())
```

Why we write mode() with [0]?

Comment: `Series.mode` returns a `Series` object.

Answer (score 0):

Because if multiple values with same maximum occurencies `mode` return all values:

```
#2 times 1 and 2
df = pd.DataFrame({'Calories':[1,1,2,2, 3]})
print (df)
   Calories
0         1
1         1
2         2
3         2
4         3

print (df["Calories"].mode())
0    1
1    2
dtype: int64
```

So for first mode value (scalar) use indexing:

```
print (df["Calories"].mode()[0])
1
```